# Qt Dialog/Widget with Next/Back Buttons

Tags: android, c++, qt, visual-c++, qt-creator

need to create an application with multiple tabbed dialog/widget with next back buttons. With each items selected in the first tab should display corresponding values in the second and so on with no provisions to click on the tab name (tabs can be accessed only by means of Back/Next buttons).

Also is is possible to change the size and shape of the tabs?

Single widget with multiple tabs with Next/Cancel button on the first page, Back/Next/Cancel Buttons on the next three pages with Back/Finish/Cancel Button on the last page.

Answer (score 2):

Qt provides a [`QWizard`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwizard.html) class which allows you to navigate with back/forward buttons. Please, take a look at example of its usage here: [Qt Wizard Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-dialogs-classwizard-example.html).